# Возможно ли с wpf передать информацию в blazor? (разные проекты)

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, blazor

появилась идея связать приложение на wpf с веб-приложением Blazor. Дело в том что я хочу реализовать систему, в которой при выборе в wpf нас бы отправляло на веб-приложение Blazor(открывается браузер).И выводило информацию по выбранному пункту в WPF, например ФИО(Иванов Иван Иванович).В Blazor вывело бы всю информацию связанную с этим пользователем. Может кто-то знает технологии для такого или библиотеки? Или есть уже готовый метод. И да у обоих проектов одна база данных.

Comment: WPF - это клиент, а Blazor - это Web сайт, если у них одна база, то вы явно делаете что-то не то, ибо клиент не должен знать данных от базы, за это отвечать должен сайт, он должен быть некой прослойкой между клиентом и данными. Так что, ответ прост - создайте API на сайте, а на клиенте их используйте. С выбором - сделайт адрес по типу `site.ru/users/100`, где 100 - это id пользователя, ну и просто открывайте эту страницу. И да, не забывайте принимать ответы, если они были вам полезны, ибо какой смысл давать вам вообще ответ, если вы его игнорируете и не принимаете?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ простите , а можете подсказать как принимать ответы? я просто так и не понял как это сделать.

Comment: Я так понял, что вы задаете много вопросов на Stackoverflow,  но когда вам отвечают, вы даже не смотрите на эти ответы. Поэтому вам не хотят отвечать

Comment: Согласен с автором первого коммента,  В WPF, по кнопке, передаете ссылку на ваш готовый сайт с Blazor, где в параметрах ссылки указываете например Id нужного пользователя, как  уже было сказано в комменте выше ...site.ru/users/100,,  при этом приложение на WPF и любые веб-приложения на Blazor, или на MVC или на Razor-Pages, будут работать одинаково

Comment: @AndreiBrizhak я просто новичок в StackOverflow. И я еще совсем не разобрался как тут это все работает.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ в моем случае в wpf заходит один администратор и он же может редактировать данные, а вот в Blazor или MVC это отображение данных по select.

Comment: @AndreiBrizhak то есть нужно использовать атрибут HTTP GET?

Comment: Один администратор, или нет - база наружу, с доступом по публичному IP - это проблема безопасности ресурса, обычно база всегда идет локальная (доступ только внутри компании, и даже конкретного сервера). А к базе уже доступ идет через сам сайт, через уго строго прописанные инструменты (API), например делаете простой `site.ru/users/add` и отсылаете на него POST запрос с JSON данными для добавления, сайт вас идентифицирует (при помощи JWT например), проверяет ваш запрос, данные, и если все хорошо, то сам отправляет эти данные в базу.

Comment: С отображением данных тоже самое, делаете контроллер, у него Get метод, который принимает id пользователя, получится у вас `site.ru/controller/id` адрес, а логика сайта - при получение, забрать из базы нужные данные по ID и вывести их как надо (если API, то JSON структура, которую клиент уже может десериализовать и вывести как надо без лишних проблем). Как делать контроллеры и прочее - это основы ASP.NET, которые написаны в любой документации по нему, практически самым первым.

Comment: Прочел комменты, и так же советую перейти к изучению основ ASP.NET Core, можно на Метаните,  можно вот на это [ютуб канале](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLePGPxR0FDm9NehG1_SkN5ahKL6Q_ozPR) посмотреть кое-что из видео.   Начать лучше c архитектуры Razor-pages, при этом не путать синтаксис Razor, и архитектуру приложения Razor-pages, затем перейти к MVC,  затем только к Blazor-Server, затем к Blazor-WebAssembly. После этого возвращаться к постановке задачи, в вашем проекте.

Comment: @AndreiBrizhak хорошо